# VHDL simulation in real time?

Tags: real-time, vhdl

I've written some code that has an RTC component in it. It's a bit difficult to do proper emulation of the code because the clock speed is set to 50MHz so to see any 'real time' events take place would take forever. I did try to do simulation for 2 seconds in modelsim but it ended up crashing.

What would be a better way to do it if I don't have an evaluation board to burn and test using scope?

Comment: "I've written some code that has an RTC component" is a bit nebulous. In general you can think of simulating a window of time containing the events of which you are interested in modeling interaction. It can be helpful to change granularity of design specifications and move part of your design model into a test bench (test parts of your design separately).  The issue is whether or not you test all the potential cases for event interaction.

Answer (score 0):

If you could provide a little more specific example of exactly what you're trying to test and what is chewing up your simulation cycles that would be helpful.

In general, if you have a lot of code that you need to test in simulation, it's helpful if you can create testbenches of the sub-modules and test them first.  Often, if you simulate at the top (chip) level and try to stimulate sub-modules that are buried deep in the hierarchy of a design, it takes many clock ticks just to get data into and out of the sub-module.  If you simulate the sub-module directly you have direct access to the modules I/O and can test the things you want to test in that module in fewer cycles than if you try to get to it from the top level.

If you are trying to test logic that has very deep fifos that you are trying to fill or a specific count of a large counter you're trying to hit, you can either add logic to your code to help create those conditions in fewer cycles (like a load instruction on the counter) or you can force the values of internal signals of your design from the testbench itself.

These are just a couple of general ideas.  Again, if you provide more detail about what it is you're simulating there are probably people on this forum that can provide help that is more specific to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by Ciano, if you provided more information about your design we would be able to give more accurate answer. However, there are several tips that hardware designers should follow, specially for complex system simulation. Some of them (that I mostly use) are listed below:

- **Hierarchical simulation** (as Ciano, already posted): instead of simulating the entire system, try to simulate smaller set of modules.
- **Selective configuration**: most systems require some initialization processes such as reset initialization time, external chips register initialization, etc... Usually for simulation purposes a few of them are not require and you may use a global constant to jump these stages when simulating, like:

  `constant SIMULATION_ENABLE : STD_LOGIC := '1';
  ...;
  -- in reset condition:
  if SIMULATION_ENABLE = '1' then
      currentState <= state_executeSystem; -- jump the initialization procedures
  else
      currentState <= state_initializeSystem;
  end if;`

  Be careful, do not modify your code directly (hard coded). As the system increases, it becomes impossible to remember which parts of it you modified to simulate. Use constants instead, as the above example, to configure modules to simulation profile.
- **Scaled time/size constants**: instead of using (everytime) the real values for time and sizes (such as time event, memory sizes, register file size, etc) use scaled values whenever possible. For example, if you are building a RTC that generates an interrupt to the main system every 60 seconds - scale your constants (if possible) to generate interrupts to about (6ms, 60us). Of course, the scale choice depends on your system. In my designs, I use two global configuration files. One of them I use for simulation and the other for synthesis. Most constant values are scaled down to enable lower simulation time.
- **Increase the abstraction**: for bigger modules it might be useful to create a simplified and more abstract module, acting as a model of your module. For example, if you have a processor that has this RTC (you mentioned) as a peripheral, you may create a simplified module of this RTC. Pretending that you only need the its interrupt you may create a simplified model such as:

  `constant INTERRUPT_EVENTS array(1 to 2) of time := (
    32 ns,
    100 ms
  );
  process
    for i in 1 to INTERRUPT_EVENTS'length loop
      rtcInterrupt <= '0';
      wait for INTERRUPT_EVENTS(i);
      rtcInterrupt <= '1';
      wait for clk = '1' and clk'event
    end for
    wait;
  end process;`